# Python: import models in sub package

Tags: python, import, package, structure

I'm pretty new to Python and I have been battling with the import for quit a bit now. I can't fully wrap my head around this concept. I have experience in ruby where the import concept is quite different.

**1. The situations**
I have this package

```
├── convortal
│   ├── dbconf.yaml                                                                                            
│   ├── helpers.py                                                                                             
│   ├── __init__.py                                                                                            
│   ├── models                                                                                                 
│   │   ├── company.py                                                                                         
│   │   ├── country.py                                                                                         
│   │   ├── ez_key.py                                                                                          
│   │   ├── __init__.py                                                                                        
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc                                                                                       
│   │   ├── product_function.py                                                                                
│   │   ├── __pycache__                                                                                        
│   │   │   ├── company.cpython-34.pyc                                                                         
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc                                                                        
│   │   └── traveler_profile.py                                                                                
│   └── __pycache__                                                                                            
│       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc                                                                            
├── README.md                                                                                                  
├── requirements.txt                                                                                           
└── setup.py
```

**convortal/__init___.py**

```
import sys
from convortal.models import *
import convortal.helpers as hp

from dbconn import CtrlSession
from sqlalchemy import desc

# DECLARATIONS FOR SETUP.PY
APP_NAME = 'convortal'
__versionnum__ = ('0','0','1')
APP_VERSION = '.'.join([i for i in __versionnum__])

def convortal(argv):
....(code to read file and update DB)
```

**convortal/models/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = [
    'Company',         
    'Country',         
    'EzKey',
    'ProductFunction', 
    'TravelerProfile', 
]

from dbconn import DBconn
from convortal.models.company import Company
from convortal.models.country import Country
from convortal.models.ez_key import EzKey
from convortal.models.product_function import ProductFunction
from convortal.models.traveler_profile import TravelerProfile
# create a connection to the DB 
conn = DBconn('PROD')  
# instantiate a Base object with this connection
Base = conn.Base()
```

**Company model: convortal/models/company.py**

```
import convortal
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from models import Base

class Company(Base):
...company table with autoload
```

**What I want to achieve**

I'm trying to create a package that can be imported to use this code with a routine that checks on a directory, collects a file with users and using this package updates, creates, or deactivates this users.

Also I'm trying to test this from the command line executing the app like this

```
(venv) ➜  convortal git:(master) ✗ python convortal/__init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` has the if statement

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    convortal(sys.argv[1:])
```

running this command should exit the app and show a message with a help string showing the arguments needed to execute the app.

**The problem**

I'm stuck with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convortal/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from convortal.models import *
ImportError: No module named 'convortal'
```

Comment: Why not just `from .models import ...`. And have you run the `setup.py` to actually install the app?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I'm using ipython to import the package, but I get the same error if I include the imports and `__all__ ` variable in the models `__init__.py` file. Removing the imports for the models I was able to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after battling for a week with my manager helping, we found the solution. I just want to share it in case someone else is having the same issue.

**project layout**

```
├── dbconf.yaml
├── helpers.py
├── __init__.py
└── models
    ├── company.py
    ├── country.py
    ├── ez_key.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── product_function.py
    └── traveler_profile.py
```

**convortal/__init__.py**

```
import sys
from . models import *
from . import helpers as hp
from sqlalchemy import desc

# DECLARATIONS FOR SETUP.PY
APP_NAME = 'convortal'
__versionnum__ = ('0','0','1')
APP_VERSION = '.'.join([i for i in __versionnum__])

def convortal(site_path, country_abbr):
....(code to read file and update DB)
```

**convortal/models/__init__.py**

```
__all__ = [
    'Company',
    'Country',
    'EzKey',
    'ProductFunction',
    'TravelerProfile',
]

from dbconn import DBconn
# create a connection to the DB
conn = DBconn('prod')
# instantiate a Base object with this connection
Base = conn.Base()

from . company import Company
from . country import Country
from . ez_key import EzKey
from . product_function import ProductFunction
from . traveler_profile import TravelerProfile
```

**Company model: convortal/models/company.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .. models import Base

class Company(Base):
...company table with autoload
```

With this layout I was able to query the DB from **convortal/__init__.py** and maintain the relations between the tables.

To execute a request, in this case you would have to follow this steps:
1. instantiate a session:

`session = convortal.models.conn.get_session()`

2. make the request

`qtest = session.query(convortal.models.EzCompany).filter_by(some_property=value)`

The order in the **convortal/models/__init__.py** matters. Because I'm using `Base` in the rest of the modules in models package I had to create the `Base` variable before importing the models

It needs to be refactor to not use `from . models import *`